# MySQL multiple query from multiple databases

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I merge these two queries into 1? Both are using 2 different databases but are all on same server. Would I use sub-selects or union here?

I basically would want something like to display the following:

```
User name | Total A | Total B
jon           5          3
tim           4          2
sarah         3          1
```

Here are the queries:

First query:

```
SELECT
  U.USR_USERNAME AS `User Name`,
  COUNT(rp_workflow.PIG.APP_UID) AS 'Total A'
FROM
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_GRID PIG
  JOIN
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
  ON PIG.APP_UID = PIN.APP_UID
  JOIN
  wf_workflow.USERS U
  ON PIN.USR_UID_ORDER = U.USR_UID
GROUP BY
U.USR_USERNAME
```

Second query:

```
SELECT
  U.USR_USERNAME AS `User Name`,
  COUNT(rp_workflow.PIQG.APP_UID) AS 'Total B'
FROM
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_QC_GRID PIQG
  JOIN
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
  ON PIQG.APP_UID = PIN.APP_UID
  JOIN
  wf_workflow.USERS U
  ON PIN.USR_UID_QC = U.USR_UID
  WHERE
  PIN.APP_STATUS = 'Completed'
 GROUP BY
 U.USR_USERNAME
```

**Edit:** tried a subselect but it ended up only displaying the sum of all values for 2nd query.  Feel like i'm close but also getting more confused.

```
SELECT
  U.USR_USERNAME AS `User Name`,
  COUNT(rp_workflow.PIG.APP_UID) AS 'Total A',
  (SELECT
    COUNT(rp_workflow.PIQG.APP_UID)
  FROM
      rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_QC_GRID PIQG
  JOIN
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
  ON PIQG.APP_UID = PIN.APP_UID
  JOIN
  wf_workflow.USERS U
  ON PIN.USR_UID_QC = U.USR_UID
  WHERE
  PIN.APP_STATUS = 'Completed') AS 'Total B'
FROM
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_GRID PIG
  JOIN
  rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
  ON PIG.APP_UID = PIN.APP_UID
  JOIN
  wf_workflow.USERS U
  ON PIN.USR_UID_ORDER = U.USR_UID
GROUP BY
U.USR_USERNAME
```

What it displayed:

```
User name | Total A | Total B
jon           5          6
```

**Edit 2: *the USR_UID are not present in tables PIG or PIQG so they must be joined to tables PIN.  From there, the username can be retrieved**

tried this query but ended up getting an unknown column error:

```
    SELECT wf_workflow.U.USR_USERNAME AS `User Name` ,

      (SELECT count(PIG.APP_UID)
       FROM rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_GRID PIG
       JOIN rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN ON PIG.APP_UID = PIN.APP_UID
       AND PIN.USR_UID_ORDER = U.USR_UID) AS 'Total A',

      (SELECT count(PIQG.APP_UID)
       FROM rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_QC_GRID PIQG
       JOIN rp_workflow.PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN2 ON PIQG.APP_UID = PIN2.APP_UID
       AND PIN2.USR_UID_ORDER = wf_workflow.U.USR_UID
       WHERE PIN2.APP_STATUS = 'Completed') AS 'Total B'
    FROM wf_workflow.USERS U
```

Comment: Try putting database name just before table name like this. - `[Db Name].[Table Name]`

Comment: @MikeBrant I tried a subselect but it only displayed the sum of all values for the 2nd query. see first post

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT username,
       SUM(CASE WHEN source = 1 THEN total END) total_a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN source = 2 THEN total END) total_b
  FROM
(
    SELECT 1 source,
           u.usr_username username,
           COUNT(pig.app_uid) total
      FROM rp_workflow.pmt_insp_grid pig JOIN rp_workflow.pmt_insp_normal pin
        ON pig.app_uid = pin.app_uid JOIN wf_workflow.users u
        ON pin.usr_uid_order = u.usr_uid
     GROUP BY u.usr_username
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 source,
           u.usr_username username,
           COUNT(piqg.app_uid) total
      FROM rp_workflow.pmt_insp_qc_grid piqg JOIN rp_workflow.pmt_insp_normal pin
        ON piqg.app_uid = pin.app_uid JOIN wf_workflow.users u
        ON pin.usr_uid_qc = u.usr_uid
      WHERE pin.app_status = 'Completed'
     GROUP BY u.usr_username
) q
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: am I to replace the "source" with the actual database names? the two separate db's are, "rp_workflow" and "wf_workflow"

Comment: No you shouldn't do that. `source` is just an alias for an injected column with constant values that we use in the outer `SELECT` for conditional aggregation.

Comment: @justWired Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong but i tried this late last night and it says "Table 'rp_workflow.pmt_insp_grid' doesn't exist".  Copied it exactly how you provided. tried retyping it then it moved on to the next table saying the same thing over and over. :/

Comment: To help you further you need to provide exact table schemas in both databases, because it's impossible to suggest something being absolutely "blind" (just looking at your queries)

Comment: i understand. Though providing all the table schema layouts will take a while and will clutter this up I think.  Basically, both tables need to be grouped by the wf_workflow.users.usr_username so I think that table needs to be the primary based on re-evaluation. See original post. I tried to rewrite the query but ended up getting an "unknown column 'U.USR_UID' in 'on clause' error. Will try to revise it again.